# Is there a mongodb proxy or triggers to calls custom script

Tags: mongodb, azure

I have a client which pushes data to my mongodb server. This is on-premise. I would like to push this data to cloud as well.
I cannot update my client software. What possibilities do I have to send this data to mongodb as well to the cloud. Here are few of them that I can think of

```
1) Setup a proxy in between to send data to mongodb and to the cloud service ( Is it possible with my current setup?)
2) Add triggers in mongodb, to call a custom script and send data to cloud when something is written to it ? ( Possible ? )
```

Please help me explore these possibilities and any references

Comment: Is pushing to the cloud just a way of backing up the data you have on-premise?

Comment: We have some limitations with on premise. Also we have a kafka setup oncloud. Would like to publsh it there